# react native android 64k method limit

Tags: android, react-native

Al hacer el build a mi aplicacion me salen estos errores:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 
65536
```

y varios mas, segun investigue este error es porque se paso el limite de metodos, ya intente habilitar el multidex pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, de hecho ya quite todas las dependencias y sigue el mismo error.
 Este es mi build.gradle solo con unas cuantas dependencias

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  mavenCentral()
}

 dependencies {
  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.4'
}
 }
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'


repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
 flavorDimensions "default"
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

 defaultConfig {

applicationId 'com.sitiorandom.muyanda'
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 26
versionCode 2
versionName '0.1.1'
ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
}

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
// Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
manifestPlaceholders = [
  'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
]
multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
}
productFlavors {
// Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
dev {
  // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
  // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
  // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
  minSdkVersion 19
}
devRemoteKernel {
  minSdkVersion 19
}
dev19 {
  // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
  // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
  minSdkVersion 19
}
prod {
  // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
  minSdkVersion 19
}
  } 
  buildTypes {
debug {
  debuggable true


}
release {
  minifyEnabled true
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  zipAlignEnabled true

}
  }
  signingConfigs {
debug {
  storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
}
 }
  lintOptions {
abortOnError false
  }  
  packagingOptions {
pickFirst "**"
  } 
 }

// Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
// crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
// locale-specific date functions are called.
// configurations.all {
//   resolutionStrategy {
//     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
//   }
// }


apply from: 'expo.gradle'


dependencies {
  implementation('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



  // Our dependencies

  //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM 
   EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  /*compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
  exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! 
  Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See 
  Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'


  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4- 
  beta1'
  compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
  compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
   transitive = false
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. 
  Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator- 
  v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

  */
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'

  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:27.0.0@aar') {
  transitive = true
  }

  //compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:27.0.0@aar')
  }

 // This has to be down here for some reason
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Y el mainApplication

```
package host.exp.exponent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import expolib_v1.okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

// Needed for `react-native link`
// import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;

public class MainApplication extends ExpoApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}

public boolean isDebug() {
return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}

// Needed for `react-native link`
public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    // Add your own packages here!
    // TODO: add native modules!

    // Needed for `react-native link`
    // new MainReactPackage()
);
}

@Override
public String gcmSenderId() {
return getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldUseInternetKernel() {
return BuildVariantConstants.USE_INTERNET_KERNEL;
}

public static OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder(OkHttpClient.Builder 
 builder) {
// Customize/override OkHttp client here
return builder;
}
}
```

Comment: Según el enlace que pones, te faltaría hacer un par de cosas todavía, te faltaría añadir una dependencia y algo más, mira en el enlace donde pone "debes usar la biblioteca de compatibilidad de MultiDex, como se indica a continuación". Ahí te dice, además de poner el multiDexEnabled true, tienes que añadir una dependencia y hacer algo más

Comment: Agrega la dependencía como menciona @RereRoro1

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, el mensaje indica el problema:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K.

Revisa la información relacionada en [Configurar apps con métodos de más de 64K](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Para que use la configuración multidex debes definir dentro del bloque `defaultConfig` y agregar su dependencia :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}


   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   }
```

definelo abajo de `targetSdkVersion`, debes asegurar no exista error y se sincronice correctamente tu archivo `build.gradle` con el proyecto.